# Strange thing with a printer driver dll in windows 10

Tags: windows, dll, printers

I've a Xerox DocuColor 250, and windows 10. I'm trying to fix a problem that will crash any program when I go to printer preferences.
The strange thing is that: if I open the control panel, printer preferences works good whitout any problem. But if I open printer preferences from for example Word the program will crash and close. On the event viewer I see:

- The module that generated the error: harmony10.dll, version: 2.6.102.0.
- The path: ": C:\Windows\system32\spool\DRIVERS\x64\3\harmony10.dll"
- The error offset "0x00000000000f5dc0"

How is possible that the same thing on the control panel won't crash but with a program it crash with this error?

If the problem won't solved with some windows-tricks, how can I track and debug a program and check what thing don't work and trying to "hack" the dll to bypass the error?

Comment: To state the obvious, this is not a programming related question.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all software associated with the printer, open the command line
and execute the `printui /s` command.
Next, look for your printer and remove the driver completely.
then install driver into printer disk or download here http://www.support.xerox.com/support/docucolor-240-250/downloads/enus.html?operatingSystem=win10

Also, try to open a command prompt on behalf of the administrator and enter:

```
net stop spooler
del %systemroot%\system32\spool\printers\*.*
net start spooler
exit
```